# Parsing site in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having a problem parsing a site for a client. I want to parse the https://okchanger.com/exchangers URL. I have tried post requests using headers and a payload which consists of some form data for the site. When I inspected the site in the networks tab, there was post request to data-table and get for the page itself. I would like to get the names and URLs, but the HTML source doesn't seem to show them (When parsing the HTML and look for the elements, it shows me an empty list). Can you kindly please tell me how would you approach this? Thanks in advance.

```
import re
import time
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class okchangerScraper:
    def __init__(self, URL):
        self.URL = URL
        self.headers = {
            'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'content-length': '1835',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'cookie': '__RequestVerificationToken=N5w7MfY6iyx6ExDA6a7kFlKD6rSeYuYE-ExXkw_hOAIK5TpeSb6YUgSPMWWEypMzYNjVELCxA41W7XE0oTJtlLa4TJNIMmsvya8CTCHRkxM1',
            'origin': 'https://www.okchanger.com',
            'referer': 'https://www.okchanger.com/exchangers',
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
            'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

    def scrape_this_page(self, page):
        with requests.session() as s:
            s.headers = self.headers

            payload = {
                'draw': '2',
                'columns[0][data]': 'Logo',
                'columns[0][name]': None,
                'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
                'columns[0][search][value]': None,
                'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[1][data]': 'Name',
                'columns[1][name]': None,
                'columns[1][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[1][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[1][search][value]': None,
                'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[2][data]': 'ReserveUSD',
                'columns[2][name]': None,
                'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[2][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[2][search][value]': None,
                'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[3][data]': 'Rates',
                'columns[3][name]': None,
                'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[3][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[3][search][value]': None,
                'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[4][data]': 'AlexaRank',
                'columns[4][name]': None,
                'columns[4][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[4][orderable]': 'false',
                'columns[4][search][value]': None,
                'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[5][data]': 'Popularity',
                'columns[5][name]': None,
                'columns[5][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[5][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[5][search][value]': None,
                'columns[5][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[6][data]': 'Status',
                'columns[6][name]': None,
                'columns[6][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[6][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[6][search][value]': None,
                'columns[6][search][regex]': 'false',
                'columns[7][data]': 'PositiveReviews',
                'columns[7][name]': None,
                'columns[7][searchable]': 'true',
                'columns[7][orderable]': 'true',
                'columns[7][search][value]': None,
                'columns[7][search][regex]': 'false',
                'order[0][column]': '5',
                'order[0][dir]': 'desc',
                'start': '0',
                'length': '100',
                'search[value]': None,
                'search[regex]': 'false'
            }

            r = requests.post(self.URL + page + '/data-table',
                              payload, headers=s.headers)
            h = r.status_code
            html = r.text

        soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
        table = soup.find('tbody')
        rows = table.select('tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.nowrap')
        print(h)
        print(len(rows))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = okchangerScraper('https://www.okchanger.com/')
    scraper.scrape_this_page('exchangers')
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I posted the code I have. @Sushanth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are receiving `json` here, not `html`. Try this:

```
import json
# ...
content = json.loads(r.text)
print(content)
```